In Swift, why doesn't generic with concrete type type parameter satisfy generic with boxed type type parameter?
I am using Swift 5.10. Xcode 15.3.
I have simplified my problem to the following sample:
public protocol Sweetening {}

struct Icing: Sweetening {}

struct Tang<S> { // Swift Std Lib type, cannot change.
    let s:S
}

class Cake {
    // Compiler requires `Tang` type parameter be specified.
    // I want any type that satisfies `Sweetening` protocol to be passed in.
    func c(tang:Tang<Sweetening>) -> String {
        return String(describing: tang)
    }
}

class Doughnut {
    let cake = Cake()
    
    func f() {
        // The type of `a1` is `Tang<Icing>`.
        let a1 = Tang(s:Icing())
        
        // Error on line below is:
        // Cannot convert value of type 'Tang<Icing>' to expected argument type 'Tang<any Sweetening>'
        let a2 = cake.c(tang: a1)
        // My thinking:
        // Icing conforms to Sweetening, therefore, it should satisfy `any Sweetening`.
    }
}

Nothing I have read in Swift Language Guide yet allows me to explain this to myself. I have read:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/opaquetypes
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/protocols

So, to put that code and my problem into English as best as I can reckon using the jargon from the above listed docs.
I have a function (c) with a function parameter (tang:) typed as a generic type (Tang<S>). The compiler insists that I specify the type parameter (S) of the generic type (Tang). I use the name of a protocol (Sweetening) to specify the type parameter (S). Using a protocol name here makes this a boxed type (any Sweetening). Everyone else in the world calls this an existential type.
OK. Next step.
Elsewhere (func f), I want the program to call c while passing in a Tang value. The passed in value (a1) has a concrete type (Icing) as the specified type parameter (S). The concrete type (Icing) conforms to the protocol (Sweetening).
My problem is that the compiler will not allow a concrete type conforming to a protocol being used to satisfy a generic type's type parameter that is specified as a boxed type of that same protocol.
I need a concise explanation of what is going on, because I certainly am not understanding some fundamental concept.
Also, what do I do instead? Keep in mind that I cannot modify Tang as that is a simplified abstraction of a type in Swift Standard Lib.
Finally, this problem is incredibly hard to search on. That is why I tried to explain it out in English using the most correct terms I could pull from the official docs.
